# How has the price of an amateur telescope 8-inch, f/8 finished, aluminized mirror varied over the last fifty years?

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing, mirror

During a [discussion in The Observatory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59312429#59312429) I was remembering that an 8-inch telescope mirror, polished and aluminized, cost something like \$100 to \$200 US in the mid 1970's.

Just now I've seen an [add in Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08JRW3K1T) for an 8-inch (203 mm) f/3.7 *spherical* primary with a diagonal thrown in for \$130 US. It's sort-of a data point and makes me wonder if commercial supplies of finished, aluminized amateur telescope mirrors have kept roughly constant in numerical price, or if the price when up until Chinese optics manufacturing started which brought the prices back down again.

Does anybody have a fifty year stack of Edmund Scientific catalogs handy?

**Question:** How has the price of an amateur telescope 8-inch, f/8 finished, aluminized mirror varied over the last fifty years?

It doesn't have to be exactly that kind of mirror. I just chose something typical or canonical.